# How many multiplications are needed when one applies the algorithm to computing $132^{1023} \mod 2047$?

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

Suppose the integer $a$ has binary representation $b_kb_{k-1}\cdots b_1b_0$ where $b_i$ are either $0$ or $1$. The power $x^a \mod n$ can be computed using the fast exponential algorithm. The calculation can be organized via the following table:

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    j        & $b_j$    & $X_j=x^{2^j} \mod n$   & $A_j$                     \\ \hline
    0        & $b_0$    & $X_0=x \mod n$         & $A_0=X_0^{b_0}$           \\ 
    1        & $b_1$    & $X_1=X_0^2 \mod n$     & $A_1=X_1^{b_1}A_0 \mod n$ \\ 
    2        & $b_2$    & $X_2=X_1^2 \mod n$     & $A_2=X_2^{b_2}A_1 \mod n$ \\ 
    $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$               & $\vdots$                  \\ 
    k        & $b_k$    & $X_k=X_{k-1}^2 \mod n$ & $A_k=X_k^{b_k}A_{j-1} \mod n$ \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

Each entry of the third column is obtained from the entry above by squaring and then reducting modulo $n$. Note also $A_j=A_{j-1}$ wherever $b_i=0$.

**Question:** How many multiplications are needed when one applies the algorithm to computing $132^{1023} \mod 2047$?

How would I do these problem?

Comment: Tabulars don't work on Math.SE; you're going to have to either generate an Image or use SE formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  Each time you square $132$ you double the exponent.  How many doublings are needed to get the largest power of $2$ less than $1023$?  Having computed all these $132^{2^n}$s, you need to multiply a number of them together.  How many?  How many $1$'s are in the binary representation of $1023$  Why is that useful?

Comment: So there will be $9$ doublings which leave you with $512$ because the 10th is $1024$? How do I find how many $1$'s are in the binary representation? Is it possible to do an example other than the number above?

Comment: Yes, there are $9$ squarings.  Do you know how to convert a number to binary?  If the exponent were 773, which is $1,100,000,101_2$, you then have to multiply the $512, 256, 4, 1$ powers to the power $773$.  There are four $1$ bits in the binary representation, and $4$ powers to be multiplied.  How many multiplies does that take?